# Archivo de Formato no reconocido C++

Tags: c++

Estoy utilizando una funcion con el siguiente codigo:

```
ofstream write("Archivo.txt", ios::app);
```

Y el compilador arroja el siguiente error:

*file not recognized:File format not recognized*

La sintaxis es incorrecta?

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que estás usando [`std::ofstream::write()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/). En ese caso, la sintaxis no es correcta. Los argumentos que has usado son apropiados para *abrir* un fichero, pero no para *escribir data* al fichero. Se puede abrir el fichero con el constructor, [`std::ofstream::ofstream()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/).

Con el objeto que devuelve ese constructor, puedes usar `write` para escribir los caracteres que quieras al fichero.

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea tal cual está puesta no es compatible con C++:

```
ofstream write("Archivo.txt", ios::app);
```

Los motivos concretos te los podría dar si hubieses puesto algo más de código... con lo que hay, no se si `ofstream` es una variable o un tipo, luego no puedo decirte si lo que falta es declarar una variable o usarla correctamente.

Además, el método [`write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) de `ofstream` no acepta los parámetros que le estás pasando... vamos, que esa línea no hay por donde cogerla.

La forma correcta de trabajar con ficheros es:

- Declaramos el objeto:

  ```
  // opcion 1
  std::ofstream out("Archivo.txt", ios::app);

  // opcion 2
  std::ofstream out;
  out.open("Archivo.txt", ios::app);
  ```
- Escribimos en el archivo:

  ```
  out.write("lo que quiera escribir en el archivo");
  ```
- Cerramos el stream:

  ```
  out.close();
  ```